# Close file before application is closed

Tags: android, file

I have an option in my app to save the data in run time to file.
It's working with check box by checking `isChecked` value:

```
if (cb_saveToFile.isChecked())
   saveTofile();
else
   closeTheFile();
```

Because sometimes the user forget to un-check the check box (and the file is not closed and therefore the data isn’t saved) I want to close the file automatically when the application is closed (Closed by the user via task manager only)

I tried to override `onDestroy` method but it's not helps:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    if (mFile.saveToFile)
        closeTheFile();
}
```

So the question is: how do I close the file when the application is closed?

**EDIT:**
I'm creating a file:

```
public void createFile() throws IOException {
    mFile = new File(fullFileName);
    mFile.createNewFile();
    fOut = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
    myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
}
```

And append lines using the method below:

```
public void addToFile (String data, Boolean enter) throws IOException {
    myOutWriter.append(data);
    if (enter) myOutWriter.append("\n");
}
```

I want to close the file (`myOutWriter.close()` & `fOut.close()`) when the application is closed (and not just when the user is clicking on the check-box to stop saving)

Comment: What do you mean exactly with an open file? The File object does not keep open or closed state. Do you mean that you have an open OutputStream or InputStream pointing to a file?

Comment: Have you also tried to use Method closeTheFile() in onStop or onPause?

Comment: unless you have a lot of data to write to your file continuously, I would recommend simply closing the file anytime you don't need it

Comment: @njzk2 I don't want to close the file because I'm continuing saving the background, while the application is minimize.

Comment: If you simply flush your stream every time you write to it, you should be fine without explicitly closing the file.

Comment: @njzk2 because I have an empty file when the app close brutally maybe I'm doing something wrong, can you explain me please how to do this? tnx!

Comment: add `myOutWriter.flush()` in your addToFile function

Comment: @njzk2, thank you very much!!! It's what i need!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your methods are working nice when other actions happens, so problem is in the part of the [android lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) where you call this methods.

What you want to do, must be placed in [Stopping and Restarting your app lifecicle part](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html).

You must override [`onPause()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause()) with same method, [`onDestroy()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()) is only when app is going to be killed:

**`onPause()`**

> Called as part of the activity lifecycle when an **activity is going into the background, but has not (yet) been killed**. The counterpart to onResume().

**`onDestroy()`**

> Perform **any final cleanup before an activity is destroyed**. This can happen either **because the activity is finishing** (someone called finish() on it, **or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance** of the activity to save space. You can distinguish between these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method.

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    if (mFile.saveToFile)
        closeTheFile();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but I can't use `OnPause` because it's working also when the app minimize and not only when it closed by task manager. (So I'll have issues when the user will return the app or if the user want to keep the data while the app is in the background)